# Client-server authentication, Asp.Net identity hashed passwords: Compare with second hashed password

Tags: asp.net, identity

I am facing a dilema.

I am using Asp.Net identity on a client-server app to store user accounts, roles and passwords. Just to avoid boilerplate and don't reinvent the wheel.That works.

However, I want to validate a remote client. I don't want to transmit the password by the wire, so I want to encode/hash it too and retrieve an access token.

The hashing mechanism in Asp.Net uses a random salt, included in the "PasswordHash" field in AspNetUsers table, among with the encryption algorithm, salt, version and etc.

Are there any suggestions on how to securely validate the client password? Maybe to extract the salt on the server to send/reencode the password on the client or something alike?

Server: Saved hash

Client: Password to hash/encrypt and send to server

Need to: Validate password securely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During Authentication, Validation of passwords should be done on server-side. Validate **Generated** Hash with **Stored** Hash.

To validate a password, I would try to do following steps on server.

1) Send the password from Client to Server over **Https**/**SSL**

2) **Retrieve** the User's Salt and Hash from the database.

3) **Generate** a Hash from User's Password and Stored **Salt**.

4) **Compare** the hash from database with generated Hash.

Reference: https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

Comment: Thank you. Is almost what I am doing, but also I don't want to send the user clean password by the net.